# How can we say that if $a+bi=c+di$ then $a=c$ and $b=d$, where $a,b,c,d$ are one-variable functions?

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers, complex-integration

I have been reading Paul Nahin's [book](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/357209.An_Imaginary_Tale) and in the last chapter (page number 213), he writes
$$\frac{\pi}{b}e^{-ab}=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{\cos(ax)}{b^2+x^2}\mathrm{d}x+i\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{\sin(ax)}{b^2+x^2}\mathrm{d}x$$
implies that
$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{\cos(ax)}{b^2+x^2}\mathrm{d}x=\frac{\pi}{b}e^{-ab}$$ and $$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{\sin(ax)}{b^2+x^2}\mathrm{d}x=0$$
But earlier in the same chapter he shows that $$\int_{-1}^{1}\frac{\mathrm{d}x}{x}=i\pi$$
So, how can we compare the real and imaginary parts in the first equation, when we don't know whether the integrals are real or imaginary?

Comment: Your last equation, as written, is most certainly not true. The written integral does not converge. It only makes sense if we talk about *principal value*, that is
$$\text{P.V}\int_{-1}^1\frac{1}{z}\mathrm{d}z=i\pi$$

Comment: @K.defaoite What principle value are you talking about? Are you sure about this?

Comment: @Ffjet https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_principal_value

Comment: @K.defaoite Then you're definitely wrong. See [here](http://www.pitt.edu/~jwheeler/Principal%20Values.pdf), page 6. Notice that you're not integrating a complex integral on a contour.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've just had a look at the book, it says

> if we change variables to $x = -e^{i\theta}$, with $0\leq \theta \leq \pi$ radians, then the integral becomes
> $$
> I=\int_{0}^{\pi} \frac{-i e^{i \theta} d \theta}{-e^{i \theta}}=\int_{0}^{\pi} i d \theta=i \pi
> $$

And I doubt the correctness of the variable substitution. Say, the substitution can *lead to* the extra imaginary part, and it doesn't really equal to the originial one. For example, we take $\theta=\dfrac \pi4$, then $e^{-i\frac{ \pi}{4} }=\dfrac{1-i}{\sqrt{2}}$ is not a real number, while $x$ in the originial integral must be real ($x\in[-1,-1]$).

Generally speaking, the integral $$\int_{-1}^{1}\frac{\mathrm{d}x}{x}$$ **does not** converge. If we talk about **cauchy principal value**, we can have it as
$$
V.P. \int_{-1}^1\dfrac1xdx=0
$$

Return to your question,

> when can we compare the real and imaginary parts

The answer is when all the integrals **converge**, that is, integrals of real functions over the real axis converges to real numbers.

Comment: What is the principal value of the last integral? In the comments to the question, somebody said it is indeed $i\pi$.

Comment: Ah, I am talking about [Cauchy Principle Value](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_principal_value). See [here](http://www.pitt.edu/~jwheeler/Principal%20Values.pdf).

Answer (score 1):

The integrals in the first equation are integrals of real functions over the real axis. So (if they converge) they converge to real numbers.

(That the second integral is $0$ is clear since it's the integral of an odd function.)